# Tensorflow session.run() does not proceed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running https://github.com/lordet01/segan/blob/master/train_segan.sh in my machine. The code does not proceed at line below (in model.py) :

```
sample_noisy, sample_wav, sample_z = self.sess.run([self.gtruth_noisy[0], self.gtruth_wavs[0], self.zs[0]])
```

As a tensorflow beginner, this line seems just converting nodes to tensors.

**Could you suggest any possible reason why it does not proceed from line above?**
I really appreciate any comments :)

My computing environment is as follows :
 Python 3.6.0 (installed by Anaconda),  TensorFlow 1.2.1, Cuda 8.0, TitanX(x2)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: That happened to me too. Are you using [queues](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues)?

Comment: @UtkarshAgarwal There is no error. Just program stops at line above.

Comment: @PratikDeoghare The code try to use queue (e.g. threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord) ), but it seems not relevant to sess.run().

Comment: [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/PratikDeoghare/b40b4755be29f0316614d0e63cdc3e07#file-qtp-py-L17) I copied from somewhere. (wish I could give credit to the original author). If you comment line 17 the code doesn't proceed and neither does it give any error. Try adding `sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())`.

Comment: @PratikDeoghare Thanks for the reply !  But in my case, adding sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer()) before sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) does not change any situation.

Comment: Enable VLOG and get a trace

Answer (score 1):

As the question is old, and the repository is not up-to-date with the original master branch, the optimisation of the network is not working.

Some of the changes that were introduced that are important are [here](https://github.com/santi-pdp/segan/commits/master).

So basically the reason why your model never converges(or atleast takes a long time), because of all the gradients are stored as lists.

**New additions** that are relevant to your question are :

```
def build_model(self, config):
        all_d_grads = []
        all_g_grads = []
        d_opt = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(config.d_learning_rate) #these lines are new
        g_opt = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(config.g_learning_rate) #these lines are new
```

NEW:

```
# deemphasize
c_res = de_emph(c_res, self.preemph)

#segan/data_loader method
def de_emph(y, coeff=0.95):
    if coeff <= 0:
        return y
    x = np.zeros(y.shape[0], dtype=np.float32)
    x[0] = y[0]
    for n in range(1, y.shape[0], 1):
        x[n] = coeff * x[n - 1] + y[n]
    return x
```

OLD:

```
#There is no deemphasize, having which saves a considerable amount of time.
```

And minor changes like the whole conversion to a class with all values retained as object..etc.